# Thread pendurando

Tags: c#, winforms, thread

Meu sistema possui um método que coloca cada evento disparado em uma *thread*, salvar, editar, pesquisar, tudo vai pra uma *thread*.

```
  backgroundWorker.DoWork += acaoProcessamento;
  backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, a) =>
  {
        this.ocooreuErro = a.Error != null;
        if ((a.Cancelled == true))
              this.lblDescricao.Text = "Cancelado!";            
        this.Refresh();
        this.Close();
  };

  backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += acaoConcluir;
  backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += (s, a) =>
  {
        prbProgresso.Value = Math.Min(100, a.ProgressPercentage);
        prbProgresso.Style = prbProgresso.Value == 100
            ? ProgressBarStyle.Marquee
            : ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
        prbProgresso.Visible = prbProgresso.Value > 0;
        if (a.UserState != null)
              lblDescricao.Text = a.UserState.ToString();
  };
  backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0);
  backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
  this.ShowDialog();
```

Mas uma rotina em específico quando chega nesse `this.ShowDialog();`, não dispara nenhuma `Exception`, não dá erro, nada, apenas pára a aplicação nessa linha e não anda mais. A princípio não vou postar mais códigos pois não sei qual parte do código poderia ajudar.

Comment: É WinForms ou WPF?

Comment: cuidado com esse "ocooreuErro" escrito errado.

Comment: Já verificou se a sua *thread* não está em loop infinito?

Comment: Já considerou usar http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx no lugar de *thread* bruta?

Comment: Opa Bigown, é winform, é um ponto meio delicado esse código ai pq se encontra em um form usado como herança em todos os outros da aplicação, e como peguei o bonde andando ainda não quero fazer alterações de muito impacto(mas se não tiver outro jeito...) vou verificar a possibilidade de loop.

Comment: Verifique se no Visualizador de Eventos do Windows não foi registrada uma *entry* detalhando a exceção ocorrida.
O ideal seria "envelopar" seus códigos (cada delegate, inclusive) com try/catch pra evitar encerramentos surpresa da sua aplicação.

Answer (score 1):

Sem evidências concretas do estado em que se encontra é muito difícil localizar o problema. Assim minha recomendação é ativar um trace da operação.
Logue informações relevantes do contexto em execução:

```
var linha = new StackTrace(new StackFrame(true)).GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber();
var nome = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name.ToString();
Debug.WriteLine(nome + "-" + linha + "-Variavel tal : " + sProdName );
```

Voce pode usar o [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) para capturar as mensagens.

Comment: Após alguns códigos de tratamento eu consegui ao menos explodir uma exception, onde dizia que o backgroundWorker não poderia executar mais de uma função, mas o estranho é que no Form padrão usado como herança em todos os outros Forms da solução, esse backgroundWorker chama 2 métodos de uma interface usada em todo Form herdado do FormPadrao, "PreValidarSalvar()" e "Salvar()", e por incrível que pareça tirando a parte da préValidaçãoSalvar que varia de form para form, todos os Forms são iguais, mas enfim obrigado pela atenção, outro analista irá verificar para achar uma solução, ai eu posto aqui